# Why admin privileges are required?

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, windows-server-2008-r2, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I'm logged-in as non-administrator account on Windows 2008 R2.

When I try to run the Inno-setup script under that account, I'm required to enter administrator password.

[image]

The problem is that later I can't debug that script, since it has references to `{userappdata}` variable, which means that during run-time it refers to administrator!

I wish not to be asked to provide administrator rights - not during debug nor during real installation. How to do that?
I prefer the application not to be installed by administrator. Respectively, files are installed to `{app}` (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)`) and `{userappdata}` only

How to prevent being asked to install it as administrator?
If I'd purchase a code-sign certificate for that application - would that solve that problem?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

There are tips already shared,

http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Vista_considerations

If you can make your installer friendly to standard users, then the elevation can be removed. You might first set `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` and then see what breaks. After fixing the broken pieces, you should get such an installer.

Code signing will not stop elevation prompt, if your installer still requires elevation.

Answer (score 2):

Installing anything to `%PROGRAMFILES%` (`C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` in versions of Windows supporting UAC (and even Windows XP under a non-power user or administrator account) requires administrator rights. There's no way to work around that; the normal (non-administrator) user isn't supposed to install software to `%PROGRAMFILES%`.

Comment: Thank you. Is that mean I must debug and test with Administrator account only (and its corresponding %appdata% ?)

Comment: You have to debug the *install* as an admin, because that's who is running the installation. The installer should ask if the software should be installed for the current user or all users, and install to the appropriate folder based on that choice (either `%APPDATA%` or `%COMMON_APPDATA%`). Giving administrative permissions to install doesn't mean you lose information about the account that started the installation.

Comment: Thank you. How to make the install ask if the software should be installed for the current user or all users?

Comment: It's easy to make it ask, but it won't work properly as you can't ask prior to the elevation, which is what really matters.  You have to decide up-front whether you want to make an admin installation (like the vast majority of applications) and install ONLY to per-machine locations, or to make a non-admin installation (rare) and install ONLY to per-user locations.  The Vista Considerations link in Lex Li's answer has more details.